# Lipschitz continuity condition for classes of differentiable function

Tags: calculus, optimization, lipschitz-functions

I am beginner when it comes to convex optimization and had to read a part Lecture notes of Prof Nesterov on Convex Optimization for my class (needless to say I wasn't too thrilled). I had a doubt in the explaination of classes of differentiable function given on page 20.

It says that a class of functions given by $C_L^{k,p}(Q)$ has the following properties:

$ f \in C_L^{k,p}(Q)$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable on $Q$

The $p$th derivative is Lipschitz continuous on $Q$ with the constant $L$:
$$\|f^{(p)}(x)-f^{(p)}(y)\| \leq L\|x-y\|$$
for all $x,y \in Q$

Then it states two statements that I didn't understand:

1) And clearly, we always have $p\leq k$

2) If $q \geq k$ then $C_L^{q,p}(Q) \subseteq C_L^{k,p}(Q)$

Could somebody please explain why the following two hold true? How would a function not be Lipschitz continuous but still have higher derivatives? How does the second statement hold?